# How to find the location of my target in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

I've been told to slay the night creature Ur Mistskinny in Pimpleumbras the Playful Holes. How can I find it? If I go to the `Q`uest log and `z`oom, I'm pointed to the area where I got the quest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that's where it lives! Some of the new night creatures (in 0.34.02) can successfully masquerade as citizens, so your questgiver might be asking you to kill someone who lives just across town. Of course, finding him is now going to be a minor exercise in tedium, since you just to walk around town talking to people until you find the right one. And I recommend killing him out of sight of other citizens; they might get upset.

If this is not the case, look at biomes and other locations nearby to see if there's one with the right name. Sometimes these "kill" quests are just kind of annoying.

Comment: You're right! There was a lair in the same map section.

Comment: Keep asking citizens in the same town about "Service". They will tell you which direction the house the vampire's house is in. If they don't give a direction that means he's in that very house! The vampire will be blinking slightly. Accuse him in front of others and everyone will join in the fight.